# How to handle multiple fieldnames and values as variables using mongoose "where" method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am using the `where` method to pass the fieldname and the value to a Mongoose fineOne query.

```
Model.findOne().where(field1,value1).where(field2, value2).exec(function(err,callback) {
   ...
}
```

The above works find. However, my problem is that we have more fieldnames and values to be passed to the above statement. I don't know exactly the number of fieldname and the value to be used since it depends on the user's configuration. I like to use a for loop to dynamically build the where clause, but don't know how. Can someone help?

Comment: Where are you getting fields and values to use in the query?  Is it in an array?  It would help if you edited your question to show that.

Comment: Sorry, I did not make it clear. The fieldnames, field1 and field2, are actually from an array, i.e., [p_last_name, p_first_name, ...]. The number of fieldnames depend on the user's configurations. So far, if I hard coded the fieldname and the value with the ".where" statement, e.g.., field1='p_last_name', field2='p_first_name', value1='Doe', value2='Joe', I was able to use the ".where(field1, value).where(field2, value)" to get the correct answer. My hope is to use my fieldname array to dynamically build a where clause or any other possible ways to get it work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a `values` object that contains the values of the fields you want to save, and a `fields` array that contains the name of the fields to save, you could do it like this:

```
var values = {p_last_name: 'Smith', p_first_name: 'John', ... };
var fields ['p_last_name', 'p_first_name'];

var query = Model.findOne();
for (var i=0; i<fields.length; ++i) {
    var field = fields[i];
    query.where(field, values[field]);
}
query.exec(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable for the conditions:

```
var conditions = {};
for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) { 
    conditions['field' + i] = 'value' + i;
}
```

The `conditions` object will look like this:

```
console.log(conditions);
Object {field1: "value1", field2: "value2"}
```

This for loop is of course just an example, you can use kind of loop to build the object. Then you can execute the `findOne()` query this way:

```
Model.findOne(conditions, function(err, item) {
  // ...
});
```